# Why is CGAL significantly slower under Windows?

Tags: c++, optimization, cgal

The Windows version my software is 2-3 times slower than the Linux version. To debug that and to demonstrate the problem I have created three simple benchmark functions:

- benchDouble() carries out some double precision computations
- benchCgalSimple() computes the intersection of two lines without high-precision numbers
- benchCgalGmpq() computes the glancing intersection of two lines such that GMPQ numbers are required

I have tuned the loops such that on my reference machine each function takes ~5 seconds:

### i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz, Linux x64

```
Time consumption: 
* START [Double precision test]...
* STOP [Double precision test]:5.21951 s

* START [CGAL simple]...
* STOP [CGAL simple]:4.98616 s

* START [CGAL GMPQ]...
* STOP [CGAL GMPQ]:4.93984 s

Factors:
  CgalSimple / Double = 0.955293
  CgalGmpq / Double = 0.946417
```

Now let's test that under Windows:

### i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz, Win10 in Virtualbox

```
* START [Double precision test]...
* STOP [Double precision test]:4.82424 s

* START [CGAL simple]...
* STOP [CGAL simple]:9.251 s

* START [CGAL GMPQ]...
* STOP [CGAL GMPQ]:12.723 s

Factors:
  CgalSimple / Double = 1.91761
  CgalGmpq / Double = 2.63732
```

...the Virtualbox and the different compiler have no significant effect because the first test takes still around 5 seconds. But the time consumption for the CGAL functions is up to 2.6 times as high.

### Xeon E5645 @ 2.4 GHz, Win10 direct (no VM)

```
Time consumption:
* START [Double precision test]...
* STOP [Double precision test]:10.1158 s

* START [CGAL simple]...
* STOP [CGAL simple]:15.8708 s

* START [CGAL GMPQ]...
* STOP [CGAL GMPQ]:20.1676 s

Factors:
  CgalSimple / Double = 1.5689
  CgalGmpq / Double = 1.99366
```

...on an old Xeon server the result is similar, the CGAL functions are up to 2 times slower than the double precision test.

### Compile conditions:

I have used CGAL-4.13.1. CGAL and the benchmark program have been compiled under Win10 with VS2015.  I have already tried various optimization options. The last test has been carried out with the command:

(Edit: Optimization setting changed to O2)

/MP /GS- /TP /GL /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"c:\benchCgal" /I"c:\benchCgal\3rdParty_64\boost_1_68_0" /I"c:\local\CGAL-4.13.1" /I"c:\local\CGAL-4.13.1\build\include" /I"c:\local\CGAL-4.13.1\build\include\CGAL" /I"C:\local\CGAL-4.13.1\auxiliary\gmp\include" /I"C:\benchCgal\winBuild2" /I"C:\local\CGAL-4.13.1\lib\cmake\CGAL......\include" /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /Fd"benchCgal.dir\Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /GT /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /Fa"Release/" /EHsc /Fo"benchCgal.dir\Release\" /Ot /Fp"benchCgal.dir\Release\benchCgal.pch"

### Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT dbl;
typedef K::Line_3 Line_3;
typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> TimePoint;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double> Duration;

using namespace std;

double stopWatch(const std::string& s)
{
        static bool bRunning(false);
        static TimePoint start;
        if(bRunning)
        {
                Duration d(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start);
                cout<<"* STOP ["<<s<<"]:"<<d.count()<<" s"<<endl<<endl;
                bRunning=false;
                return d.count();
        }
        else
        {
                cout<<"* START ["<<s<<"]..."<<endl;
                bRunning=true;
                start=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                return -1;
        }
}

double sum(1.0);
void benchDouble()
{
    for(double i=0;i<185;i+=1.0)
    {
            for(double j=0;j<1000;j+=1.0)
            {
                    for(double k=0;k<1000;k+=1.0)
                    {
                            sum+=sqrt(i*i+j*j+k*k)*sqrt(i*k+j*k+i*j);
                            sum+=cos(.00314*k)+sin(.00314*k);
                            sum/=(i+k+j*j+1);
                    }
            }
    }
}

double benchCgalSimple()
{
    double sum(0);
    for(int i=0;i<3731000;++i)
    {
        Point_3 p0(0,0,0);
        Point_3 p1(2,0,0);
        Point_3 p2(1,1,0);
        Point_3 p3(1,-1,0);
        Line_3 line0(p0,p1);
        Line_3 line1(p2,p3);
        if(!do_intersect(line0,line1)) continue;
        CGAL::Object obj(CGAL::intersection(line0,line1));
        Point_3 isp;
        bool bOK(CGAL::assign(isp,obj));
        if(bOK) sum+=to_double(isp.x()+isp.y()+isp.z());
    }
    return sum;
}

double benchCgalGmpq()
{
    double sum(0);
    for(int i=0;i<96198;++i)
    {
        Point_3 p0(0,0,0);
        Point_3 p1(1,DBL_MIN,DBL_MIN);
        Point_3 p2(2,DBL_MIN,DBL_MIN);
        Point_3 p3(3,0,0);
        Line_3 line0(p0,p1);
        Line_3 line1(p2,p3);
        if(!do_intersect(line0,line1)) continue;
        CGAL::Object obj(CGAL::intersection(line0,line1));
        Point_3 isp;
        bool bOK(CGAL::assign(isp,obj));
        if(bOK) sum+=to_double(isp.x().exact()+isp.y().exact()+isp.z().exact());
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Benchmarks started..."<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Time consumption: "<<endl;
    stopWatch("Double precision test");
    benchDouble();
    double timeDouble=stopWatch("Double precision test");

    stopWatch("CGAL simple");
    benchCgalSimple();
    double timeCgalSimple=stopWatch("CGAL simple");

    stopWatch("CGAL GMPQ");
    benchCgalGmpq();
    double timeCgalGmpq=stopWatch("CGAL GMPQ");

    cout<<"Factors:"<<endl;
    cout<<"  CgalSimple / Double = "<<timeCgalSimple/timeDouble<<endl;
    cout<<"  CgalGmpq / Double = "<<timeCgalGmpq/timeDouble<<endl;
}
```

**Note:** The above test computes not only the absolute time consumptions but also two factors that compare the CGAL-functions with the non-CGAL function. These factors are around 1.0 under Linux and up to 2.6 under Windows. Different CPU types (or in one case VM use) affect the whole program and thus the factors are still meaninful.

(edit):

## New Benchmark Data

In the discussions below the benchmark method has been discussed because Windows ran in a VM. Now a colleque ran it for me on his dual-boot machine, i7-7700 CPU @ 3.6 GHz.

WINDOWS:

```
* START [Double precision test]...
* STOP [Double precision test]:3.13713 s 
 
* START [CGAL simple]...
* STOP [CGAL simple]:7.66628 s (+86 % compared to linux)
 
* START [CGAL GMPQ]...
* STOP [CGAL GMPQ]:10.6407 s (+78% compared to linux)
```

Linux:

```
* START [Double precision test]...
* STOP [Double precision test]:4.41382 s
 
* START [CGAL simple]...
* STOP [CGAL simple]:4.10052 s
 
* START [CGAL GMPQ]...
* STOP [CGAL GMPQ]:5.97985 s
```

## New benchmark numbers with MinGW (added Oct.10th 2019)

i7-7820HQ @ 2.90 GHz, Win10 Pro, Ubuntu 18.04 as subsystem

```
CGAL GMPQ:
  Ubuntu: 4.8 s
  Win10 VS2015: 12.5 s
  Win10 MinGW:  12.5 s

CGAL simple:
  Ubuntu: 2.6 s
  Win10 VS2015: 9.1 s
  Win10 MinGW:  7 s
```

The first test is dominated by computations that require GMPQ numbers. These are equally bad with VS2015 and MinGW (2.6 times worse than under Linux). In contrast the simple test does not involve GMPQ numbers and it is 23 % faster with MinGW (although still 2.6 times worse than under Linux).

Just a thought: The operations carry out many new/delete operations. Can the memory management under Windows be so much worse? Wouldn't a memory pool - at least for internal intermediate calculations - drastically improve the performance?

Comment: How were the linux versions compiled?

Comment: Under Linux I used -O3

Comment: For Windows: "_the `/Ox` compiler option enables only a subset of the speed optimization options enabled by `/O2`_"

Comment: I don't want to defend Windows, _but_ it's not fair to compare virtualized Windows against non-virtualized Linux. (The only non-virtualized Windows is on a different CPU).

Comment: ... and not using the full set of speed optimizations (`/O2`) on Windows isn't really fair either.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks. I have changed the optimization from /Ox to /O2. The result is similar.

Comment: It's still not fair to compare behavior of code on different OSes between very different CPUs, unless it's the CPU & OS combinations which you're comparing...

Comment: @Rusian The tests show also the relative speeds of the two CGAL-functions compared to the double precision function: The factors are 1.0 under Linux but up to 2.6 on Windows machines.

Comment: @Geom I see. It was worth a try. What if you compile GCAL with the same version of g++ under Windows too? - or with  VS2019? I've gotten the impression that a lot has happened under the hood in VS since 2015.

Comment: benchDouble mostly tests sincos in the math library, I am not sure it is a good baseline. The implementation of interval arithmetic is a bit worse (but not a by factor of 2) with visual studio, because it does not have inline asm like gcc does, and I didn't spend time trying to optimize with the features it does have, like the float_control pragma. GMP could also be slower on your windows, depending how it was compiled.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, benchDouble() is simple but I think sufficient as a reference because its speed differs only by 8 % under Linux/Win10 (on the same machine) while the CGAL-Functions differ by up to 260%. I use the precompiled GMP binary from the CGAL installer. Does it make sense to move to MinGW to compile CGAL'ed software for Windows? Or is there any chance that the performance gap will be resolved in the future? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am still not convinced that benchDouble is useful: it could be that the whole windows VM is twice slower, but the math library in windows is twice faster, which compensates. Compiling with mingw on windows would give an interesting datapoint. I can't say anything about bridging the performance gap, since I don't know if it really exists, or where it is exactly.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Good point, you are right. Unfortunately I have no dualboot machine for my tests. Meantime I have also tried VS2019 but no improvement. Currently I try to install CGAL using MinGW. That's not easy. When I succeed I will add the result here.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I managed to get benchmarks from a dual-boot machine. The math library is really faster. But CGAL is still significantly slower with MSVC (I have added the new benchmark data above).

Comment: Perhaps cygwin would be an easier environment to build/install CGAL, or perhaps you can even use WSL and run a native Linux binary. it should not affect performance of code that uses no syscalls, which your benchmark shouldn't. Not sure about Wine, but in theory it shouldn't slow things down either.

Comment: It will be interesting to see how that changes in CGAL-5 (I completely changed the implementation of intervals). Do you have profiling data on windows?

Comment: I start Windows only once in a while to compile projects that I have implemented under Linux thus I do not know the Windows profiling tools well but I have pasted the complete source of my test. In case that it is interesting for your work on CGAL5 it should be easy to reproduce the results. When do you expect the release of CGAL5 ?

Comment: I probably use windows even less that you do. From history, I guess cgal-5.0 should come in October, although the absence of a beta release is a bad sign. The sources are on github if you want to play with them.

Comment: Ah, now I remember, I was blocked by https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/538697/pragma-fenv-access-fpstrict-has-no-effect-on-const.html when experimenting with more efficient code on windows.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I have added benchmark numbers with MinGW, see above. It's faster but it does not close the gap.